# Wait for key pressed using key bindings in java

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings

I am a beginner writing a quiz game in Swing Java, i want the user/s to answer a question by pressing a key.
I have trouble in making the program wait till a key is pressed.

---

I have tried calling the method and then having a while loop with a Getter method for answer1 to "pause" the program until the variable is the answer that i want but the program just froze when i did that.

---

I have searched a lot but nothing quite works.
Here is a sample of the code:

```
public static void addKeyBinding(int keyCode, String id, ActionListener lambda){
    InputMap im = GUI().getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
    ActionMap am = GUI().getActionMap();
    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyCode, 0 ,false), id);
    am.put(id, new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            lambda.actionPerformed(e);
        }
    });
}


public char keyOperationSinglePlayer(){
    addKeyBinding(KeyEvent.VK_A, "A", (evt) -> {
        answer1 = 'a';
    });

    addKeyBinding(KeyEvent.VK_S, "S", (evt) -> {
        answer1 = 'b';
    });
    addKeyBinding(KeyEvent.VK_D, "D", (evt) -> {
        answer1 = 'c';
    });
    addKeyBinding(KeyEvent.VK_F, "F", (evt) -> {
        answer1 = 'd';
    });
    return answer1;
}`
```

Thanks

```
public class GUI extends JPanel
```

Comment: You should not have a while loop. The natural state of a GUI is to sit there ans do nothing. The GUI only does something when an event is generated. So the Action for your key bindings should set the "answer" and then invoke your "answer processing" logic, which might to to verify the answer and then display the next question.

Comment: *"answer a question by pressing a key"* Add an `ActionListener` to a text field used for the answer. Instruct the user to press Enter when they've typed an answer, the action listener will receive an action event.

Comment: but that won't work if 2 players are playing at the same time, thank you for the idea though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's been a year and I stumbled across my old project and decided for anyone interested to post what i finally did.

```
 /**
 * Assigns keys and then invokes the methods of "answer processing" logic
 *
 * @throws IOException , exception
 */
public void keyAssignment() throws IOException {
    //key assignment
    CorrectAnswer ca = CorrectAnswer.CorrectAnswer();
    Betting b = Betting.Betting();
    Questions questions = Questions.Question();
    Rounds rounds = Rounds.Rounds();
    //reset keys
    answer1 = ' ';
    answer2 = ' ';
    game3Panel.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            //super.keyTyped(e);
            char temp;
            switch (e.getKeyChar()){
                case 'a' :
                    //a for player 1
                    answer1 = 'a';
                    delUpdatedScreen();
                    temp = questions.getCorrectLetter();
                    if(rounds.getRound().equals("ca")){
                        ca.setPoints(resultPane(answer1, temp), 1);
                    }
                    if(rounds.getRound().equals("b")){
                        b.setPoints(resultPane(answer1, temp), 1);
                    }
                    break;
                case 's' :
                    //b for player 1
                    answer1 = 'b';
                    delUpdatedScreen();
                    temp = questions.getCorrectLetter();
                    if(rounds.getRound().equals("ca")){
                        ca.setPoints(resultPane(answer1, temp), 1);
                    }
                    if(rounds.getRound().equals("b")){
                        b.setPoints(resultPane(answer1, temp), 1);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'd' :
                    //c for player 1
                    answer1 = 'c';
                    delUpdatedScreen();
                    temp = questions.getCorrectLetter();
                    if(rounds.getRound().equals("ca")){
                        ca.setPoints(resultPane(answer1, temp), 1);
                    }
                    if(rounds.getRound().equals("b")){
                        b.setPoints(resultPane(answer1, temp), 1);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'f' :
                    //d for player 1
                    answer1 = 'd';
                    delUpdatedScreen();
                    temp = questions.getCorrectLetter();
                    if(rounds.getRound().equals("ca")){
                        ca.setPoints(resultPane(answer1, temp), 1);
                    }
                    if(rounds.getRound().equals("b")){
                        b.setPoints(resultPane(answer1, temp), 1);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'h' :
                    if(players == 2){
                        //a for player 2
                        answer2 = 'a';
                        delUpdatedScreen();
                        temp = questions.getCorrectLetter();
                        if(rounds.getRound().equals("ca")){
                            ca.setPoints(resultPane(answer2, temp), 2);
                        }
                        if(rounds.getRound().equals("b")){
                            b.setPoints(resultPane(answer2, temp), 2);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                case 'j' :
                    if(players == 2){
                        //b for player 2
                        answer2 = 'b';
                        delUpdatedScreen();
                        temp = questions.getCorrectLetter();
                        if(rounds.getRound().equals("ca")){
                            ca.setPoints(resultPane(answer2, temp), 2);
                        }
                        if(rounds.getRound().equals("b")){
                            b.setPoints(resultPane(answer2, temp), 2);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                case 'k' :
                    if(players == 2){
                        //c for player 2
                        answer2 = 'c';
                        delUpdatedScreen();
                        temp = questions.getCorrectLetter();
                        if(rounds.getRound().equals("ca")){
                            ca.setPoints(resultPane(answer2, temp), 2);
                        }
                        if(rounds.getRound().equals("b")){
                            b.setPoints(resultPane(answer2, temp), 2);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                case 'l' :
                    if (players == 2){
                        //d for player 2
                        answer2 = 'd';
                        delUpdatedScreen();
                        temp = questions.getCorrectLetter();
                        if(rounds.getRound().equals("ca")){
                            ca.setPoints(resultPane(answer2, temp), 2);
                        }
                        if(rounds.getRound().equals("b")){
                            b.setPoints(resultPane(answer2, temp), 2);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And this is the snippet of code that invokes it.

```
            game3Panel = new JPanel();
            game3Panel.setOpaque(false);
            game3Panel.setVisible(false);
            game3Panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            BoxLayout boxlayout = new BoxLayout(game3Panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
            game3Panel.setLayout(boxlayout);

            picLabel = new JLabel();
            picLabel.setIcon(null);
            game3Panel.add(picLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            cat = new JLabel("");
            game3Panel.add(cat);

            question = new JLabel("");
            game3Panel.add(question);

            ans1 = new JLabel("");
            game3Panel.add(ans1);

            ans2 = new JLabel("");
            game3Panel.add(ans2);

            ans3 = new JLabel("");
            game3Panel.add(ans3);

            ans4 = new JLabel("");
            game3Panel.add(ans4);

            frame.setVisible(true);

            frame.setFocusable(false);
            try {
                keyAssignment();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

This **is not** the best solution to this problem and it is kinda rushed but i was new to programming and in a hurry to finish before the deadline, so if you have a better solution, or want more clarifications on the code, don't hesitate to let me know! :)